# How to watch "Day of the Doctor" if you don't have access to a broadcasting TV station or a cinema?

Tags: doctor-who

I recently heard about the 50-year-anniversary special [Day of the Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor), due to air 2013-11-23 19:30:00 +00 (UTC). However, I cannot receive any station that would broadcast the episode where I live, nor is a cinema near by.

Is there any way to receive the programme live (real time) via the Internet?

*Note: In particular I'm looking for a way to see it in Germany, but I deem a general question more useful to the site.*

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/

Comment: Rethinking my answer and the question... do you actually have any digital TV or just analog or satellite? Would help as well I guess.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Appears to be overkill for one episode ...

Comment: @bitmask: I’m sorry, I was under the impression you were a *real fan*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about media recommendations

Comment: @bitmask heathen.

Comment: @DVK: [Doesn't seem](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) like a [clear cut](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/350/2565). What do you base your off-topic claim on, exactly?

Comment: @bitmask  - Doesn't seem like there can be a correct answer aside from "torrent it"

Comment: @bitmask - under old rules it'd also fall under "localized". As in, nobody would ever need to know this answer after the date passes.

Comment: @DVK: Well, it might be temporally localised to some extent, but I'd think it has relevance for broad audience. At any rate, "torrent it" is an extremely poor answer. Even if I wanted to, it wouldn't be up right when the episode is airing. And since when do *you* subscribe to "I cannot think of an answer, so let's click the close button"?

Comment: @bitmask - it's more of "this belongs on chat for like 3 distinct reasons". I just picked one button more or less at random as none fit precisely. And yes, I'm a philthy hypicrite. Guilty.

Comment: @bitmask - your question didn't say " right when the episode is airing" anywhere so torrent would fit as an answer, leaving aside legal/ethical angle

Comment: @DVK: Thanks for the suggestion. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2):

As with the previous seasons, **FOX** Germany will air the episode on **23rd November 2013 at 21:00-22:20 CET** (dubbed I guess; might still change), however this is pay TV and will require a subscription including it.

This is really interesting considering the short time difference (I assume your airing date is the UK one?).

I don't think there's any easy way watching it online. You might have luck using some UK based VPN service, but I'm not really sure whether BBC shows it online, or some online recording service.

Edit:
I just checked and onlinetvrecorder.com now supports recording of most BBC stations (if you're a paid user), so I guess you'd be able to let them record the episode and download it shortly after (although I remember the usage being rather tricky and sometimes annoying; requires a 60 cents payment for 30 days).

Comment: I know about Fox Germany airing it, but I don't have a subscription. As I don't really like our TV programme, I don't even use my TV for its original purpose (no cable). But I think we have a satellite dish in the office, and we were thinking if maybe we could watch it all together. However, neither Fox nor cinemas appear to be an option.

Comment: Yeah, thinking similar, although pay TV has quite some good shows or series (like the Doctor :)) - office sounds like a good last resort if you prefer watching it "live".

Comment: BBC has an online streaming service but you have to live in one of their markets (basically, the UK) to use it, so that's likely not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Instant Video puts their pay-per-view streams up about 12 hours after the show airs, that's how we've watched all of the Doctor Who episodes for the past 2 seasons (we don't have cable either). It's around $3 (US) for each episode.

I'm not sure if they have Instant Video for the German version of the site. I didn't see anything that looked like it, but I can't read German.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. No streaming and similar services for Germany. Our "Amazon Prime" is really just free/fast delivery unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The BBC’s online iPlayer website now shows BBC TV channels live, e.g.:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/tv/bbc_one_london/watchlive

However, you do need to be in the UK, and *be a licence-fee payer* (you free-loading, common-market commies) in order to watch it.

I guess you could try using a proxy server, but you’d be risking a visit from Her Majesty’s UK TV Licence Enforcement Sniper Regiment.

Comment: Doesn't sound more dangerous than the German equivalent... at least BBC gets you something for your money. :)

Comment: in the future, if you don't pay your license fees the Daleks will kill you. You have been warned.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Frankly, [as final thoughts go](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=653#comic), "Holy Boly, Daleks and therefore The Doctor are real ... uargh ..." is pretty far up ... right next to the unicorn one.

Answer (score -1):

Set up screen sharing via some standard "screen share" programs (e.g. Joel Spolsky's company has one, Cisco another) with someone who has access to Amazon Prime streaming.

Or hop on a train/plane to Perfidious Albion.